# PyCharm 4.0 Terminal Window

Tags: python, terminal, pycharm

When using the terminal window in PyCharm, I cannot find a way to use a keyboard shortcut to close the terminal window, other than SHIFT+ESC. This particular keyboard shortcut is going to give me carpal tunnel. Trying to assign a custom keyboard shortcut like COMMAND+\ does not work. Also pressing the ESC key alone doesn't loose focus.

Does anyone know a way that makes it easier to close the window without a mouse? I know it seems like a minor thing but if you switch back and forth between the editor and terminal as much as I do... it matters.

Comment: This is pretty funny, but it may be off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the issue you're experiencing. I remapped "Hide Active Tool Window" to Ctrl-Shift-H in PyCharm 4.0.3 on OS X and it worked fine.

- Preferences -> (Search box) "keymap" -> (Keymap Search box) "hide active"
- Right-click, Add Keyboard Shortcut